# kotlin multiplatform with third party dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m using a third party library which is a basically a DSL that represents business model (objects and rules).
This DSL comes with java and typescript implementations. (providing .jar and .ts files)

For my backend application, written in kotlin, I have already writen some utility functions and business logic that uses this model.
I’m used to use the jar lib for the backend code, obviously.

Now I have to implement a frontend in angular.
In this frontend I will have to do some model objects manipulations as well, some will be the same purpose that the ones I’ve already written in kotlin for the backend.

I started to use the ts lib in angular and written again the utilities methods, but I wonder if it’s possible to re-use the ones already written in Kotlin ?

Is there a way to create a kotlin multiplatform project that uses the third party jar lib for common code ? and could generates both jar for backend and js (or even ts) for angular ? Does the third party ts lib could be any help in this case ?

Thanks !